# Difference between pt_regs and user_struct_regs

Tags: c, arm, cpu-registers, ptrace

I have been messing around with ptrace and registers a lot lately and I was wondering if there is a difference between pt_regs and user_struct_regs as far as content goes. More specifically, do they both hold the same content(register values) but just have different named members to hold it.

I noticed that some architectures contain user_struct_regs, while others such as arm do not have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format and layout of registers is highly architecture-specific. You have to read the definitions and comments in `/usr/include/asm/user.h` header. (For linux; the exact location might differ from OS to OS -- read the relevant ptrace documentation.)

Comment: Thanks, I now see the difference by looking at /usr/include/asm/user.h versus /usr/include/sys/user.h on Ubuntu. Do you know by chance what the pt in pt_regs stands for?

Comment: I guess it just "marks" the field for use for ptrace. IIRC, when the C language was first created, all struct fields were in a single namespace. In other words, you weren't allowed to have a field named 'regs' in two *different* structs, so you had to disambiguate field names across struct definitions. If, for example, you read the manpage for `stat` syscall, you will see the remnants of this convention also in `struct stat`, where every field is prefixed with `st_`.